# How to draw a simple connector to connect two display Object dragged on group container from Palette container in flex4.6?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Please consider the fact that it work only as a connector not as a line.Means if we move mouse after mouseDown event on group from one position to another it does not draw line.I'm using actionscript3.0 and flex4.6.